# Find n argmins in 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, min

I need to find n argmins in 2d array in python, how can I do that?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
a=np.array([[1, 5, 9], [2, 3, 10], [4, 11, 12]])
argmins = n_argmins(a, 5) # finding 5 argmins
print(argmins)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[0 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 0]]
```

Comment: isn't the result should be?
[[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 0]
[0, 1]]

Comment: You could start with an `argsort` of `a.ravel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1, 5, 9], [2, 3, 10], [4, 11, 12]])
np.c_[np.unravel_index(a.ravel().argsort()[:5], a.shape)]
```

It gives:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the data into a list but remember the original indexes.
search for n min args in the list.

code:

```
def n_argmins(a, n)
  for i,inner in enumerate(a):
     for j,x in enumerate(inner):
         indexes[x] = [i,j]
         a_new.append(x)
  res = []
  for _ in range(n):
     res.append(indexes[min(a_new)])
     a_new.remove(min(a_new))
  return res
```

assuming all the list are sorted (as shown in the example) we can solve it in a better way. The solution is based on the idea that the first values in every inner list are already the min args of that list. So we just need to search on them. code:

```
n = 5
next_possible_mins = [0]*len(a)
indexes = [0]*len(a)
result = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    next_possible_mins[i] = a[i][0]
    indexes[i] = [0, i]

for i in range(n):
    index_min = next_possible_mins.index(min(next_possible_mins))
    result.append(indexes[index_min])
    indexes[index_min] = [indexes[index_min][0]+1, indexes[index_min][1]]
    next_possible_mins[index_min] = a[indexes[index_min][1]][indexes[index_min][0]]

print(result)
```